# How to distinct column by starting from earliest/latest row with SQL query?

Tags: sql

how can I distinct the column but the row were removed is from the earliest found/retain the last?

I have tried some ways, but all of them not worked.
below is the raw, column that I want to work with

```
parent_item_id
------------------------------------
9B3E7A72-D36A-42D3-A04C-186DEC409F93
942E1854-9EB4-4C19-8A1E-4FCC4953B50C
E75C7294-F0C4-4C6E-8C12-DF5FBC93FA3B
942E1854-9EB4-4C19-8A1E-4FCC4953B50C
942E1854-9EB4-4C19-8A1E-4FCC4953B50C
```

below is the ways I tried:

1. using the default behaviour of distinct like this.
   query:

```
WITH tree AS (SELECT distinct(ic.parent_item_id) FROM dbo.item_combination ic, dbo.product p WHERE ic.child_item_id != p.item_id 
                UNION ALL
                SELECT ic.parent_item_id FROM tree t, dbo.item_combination ic WHERE t.parent_item_id=ic.child_item_id
             )
SELECT DISTINCT (parent_item_id) from tree
```

result:

```
parent_item_id
--
9B3E7A72-D36A-42D3-A04C-186DEC409F93
942E1854-9EB4-4C19-8A1E-4FCC4953B50C
E75C7294-F0C4-4C6E-8C12-DF5FBC93FA3B
```

2. using `row_number`  like this. but based on my logic it should change the order but why the final result is the same as way 1?
   query:

```
WITH tree AS (SELECT distinct(ic.parent_item_id) FROM dbo.item_combination ic, dbo.product p WHERE ic.child_item_id != p.item_id 
                UNION ALL
                SELECT ic.parent_item_id FROM tree t, dbo.item_combination ic WHERE t.parent_item_id=ic.child_item_id
             )
SELECT DISTINCT(parent_item_id) FROM 
( 
    SELECT t.parent_item_id, [row_number]=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) FROM tree t  ORDER BY [row_number] DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS
) r
group by r.parent_item_id, r.[row_number]
```

result:

```
parent_item_id
--
9B3E7A72-D36A-42D3-A04C-186DEC409F93
942E1854-9EB4-4C19-8A1E-4FCC4953B50C
E75C7294-F0C4-4C6E-8C12-DF5FBC93FA3B
```

the result I want/expected is like this.

```
parent_item_id
--
9B3E7A72-D36A-42D3-A04C-186DEC409F93
E75C7294-F0C4-4C6E-8C12-DF5FBC93FA3B
942E1854-9EB4-4C19-8A1E-4FCC4953B50C
```

Comment: I suggest, first, you learn what RDBMS you are *really* using.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "earliest" or "last" unless a column contains that information.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you show us what you've tried and explain more about what you need?

Comment: Since there are no other column, why bother if a kept row is the first or last?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only the tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: @jarlh it was the id's from recursive of tree-like structure, I need distinct like that because I want to operate the id's from first to last order.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and edit your question to show us what you tried after researching it, and what went wrong so that others can help troubleshoot a minimum reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: I already edited the question, can anyone help me?

Comment: @muazhari - ref comment from jarlh - are there any other columns that you can use to determine the preferred sort order - such as timestamp the record was written?  Your initial result set is completely accurate for "sort order" - the query cannot sort any other  way (except in reverse) with the current attributes you have supplied ...

Comment: @irnerd there aren't any columns to determine except using row_number() like way 2 that I have tried, based on my logic it should change the order but why the final result is same as way 1?

Comment: @muazhari - and anyone else - if somebody knows of alpha / numeric character set that changes the order of 
< 9B3E7A72   |   942E1854  |    E75C7294 > to < 9B3E7A72  |  E75C7294  | 
 942E1854 > - please share :)

Comment: You probably need to expose the child item id so any relationship which can be used to determine order can be mined. The main question that enables you to solve this is, what from your perspective in the data makes you believe that your final expected order can occur? If based on the traverse path, then this can be solved. If just based on that field alone and no other discernable patterns for that field alone (e.g. they both contain a 72), then this proves difficult to resolve.

Comment: To expand on @GordonLinoff's comment, unsorted means the order of the rows returned should be considered to be random. You might see the same results between executions, but there is no guarantee they will be returned in the same order, unless you specifically use an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @Chuma if based on that field alone impossible, how to solve it based on the traverse path? the rough way I think is every row has depth level, then order it by the highest level. if there has the same id, just pick the highest level. can anyone realize this? or any other alternatives?

Comment: and i wanna ask a little about "ordering", in the last code there has this query "where dbo.item.id=modified.parent_item_id". will it update the item ordered by modified.parent_item_id or in a random order?

Comment: Yes the depth level is an aspect of the recursive path or a trail of breadcrumbs. I still need to understand why you believe it should be ordered one way or the other. What are you seeing that makes you believe the order you expect is a possible result? Typically the way this should work is, you present input and present expected output, show what you have done for process and help arrives. Right now your input in incomplete because you have only presented one field out of 2 required for a recursive process. Change your input to show the other field.

Comment: the input was the combination of items, you can imagine like a product is produced from the raw item, but that product can be produced with another item again to create a new product and so on. what I want is every product has available quantity information based on the item it uses. why I believe the order is expected to a possible result because every item quantity got modified, the changes will go upward like a tree/graph. the challenge was I need to prioritize updating based on the same level first before taking the next one. .... (continue in the next comment)

Comment: the other input is an updated item. based on the graph structure, I just only use a unique updated item id to revise the item quantity that used it. what I assumed is I traversed using "WITH AS" query starting from all updated item id then have the ordered result. the result is used to revise by prioritizing the near starting item first from level by level, because if not in that order it will revise wrong. e.g. item A produced from item B (need 1) and C (need 1), the last available B&C is (3 & 3), but the current was (3, 1). if I updated in this order B,A,C it will go wrong, A have false qty.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, This is what I think should happen:

1. You need to establish a parent-child item view or a product-source view. This would look like:

```
create view v_ProductSourceMap as
SELECT ic.parent_item_id as item_id, p.item_id as source_id
FROM dbo.item_combination ic left join dbo.product p on ic.child_item_id = p.item_id 
group by ic.parent_item_id, p.item_id
```

2. Check that the view represents all items derived from other items and for new items, source_id will be null.

```
select * from v_ProductSourceMap order by item_id, source_id
```

3. Now use a recursive query to traverse the mapping

```
WITH tree AS (
SELECT item_id, source_id, 1 as depth, cast(ic.item_id as varchar(max)) as bc   
FROM v_ProductSourceMap ic
WHERE source_id is null 
UNION ALL
SELECT ic.item_id, source_id, t.depth + 1, t.bc + '>' + cast(ic.item_id as varchar(max)) 
FROM tree t, v_ProductSourceMap ic WHERE ic.source_id=t.item_id
    )
select * from tree
```

From here, look at the pattern in the depth and/or the breadcrumbs to figure out what your sort order could be.

Comment: thanks. but to perform the update task, how to order it by the highest level and if there has the same id, only choose the highest level?

Comment: You mentioned that those that get updated move up. What is move up based on? Time? If I were in a stored proc and I knew what my order was from the tree, I would insert into the temp table using that order with an identity field and then use that temp table for my updates. Since we also have "with" statements, you could add another with statement to hold the order with which you want to make updates but ... you must first determine the order you need from the tree first to make anything else possible.

Comment: i tried using this "FROM (SELECT DISTINCT t.parent_item_id, [depth]=max(depth) FROM tree t GROUP BY t.parent_item_id ORDER BY 2 OFFSET 0 ROWS) modified WHERE dbo.item.id=modified.parent_item_id", but why the updating operation still in random order?

Comment: Take a look at my last update and tell me if this is what you are trying to do. I am just going off the notion that an item is used to derive another item based on what is in the product table. If that doesn't work, you need a sql fiddle created so it can be figured out. That initial view of parent child needs to exist in some form for what you are doing to make sense.